# PyroCMS routing issue .

Tags: codeigniter, pyrocms

I have created a module in PyroCMS like mymodule and create the front controller songs.

Now I want to set the my routing from

www.example.com/mymodule/songs to  www.example.com/songs

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Haven't tested this but something like the following should work, assuming you have the URL schema `www.example.com/mymodule/songs` and `www.example.com/mymodule/songs/song_id`:

```
$route['songs'] = 'mymodule/songs';
$route['songs/(:any)'] = 'mymodule/songs/$1';
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your version you could use the routes module.

Something like: **foo/(:any) => bar/baz**